# Webpack config - Adding another entry file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

Okay, so I am having an issue with React. So I have created a NavBar component and I have it saved in JSX form in 'home.js' and it is rendering perfectly in my index.html.
Now, I want to create a "Login" component, but I realised shortly after I created the new 'login.js' file that Webpack could not "see" this file so it was not getting compiled.
I discovered that this is because I have not told the Webpack config to compile this new file, I have tried many different ways but I am unable to make Webpack compile both files. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

See my Webpack Config Below:

```
var path = require('path');
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
var buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
  context: srcPath,
  entry: path.join(srcPath, 'js', 'home.js'),
  output: {
      path: buildPath,
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
          }
      ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a sample of your code but i hope this explanation works. Use export and import to define the dependencies for your files.

eg

```
navbar.js

export class Navbar{
    // Write your component here
}

login.js

var Navbar = require('./navbar');

export class Login{
    // Write your Login component here
    // You can also use your navbar component here since it is imported
}
```

Your webpack entry point should be the login. The import will ensure that your Navbar is pulled in aswell.

I hope that gives you the idea. I dont have your code so i cant help beyond this

Comment: Sorry only getting back to you now. Thanks so much, this fixed my issue perfectly. :)

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

You could set entry as object and then pass the all files that you need.I do it in this way

```
module.exports = {

  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['./node_modules', './resources/assets/scripts']
  },

  entry: {
   main: './resources/js/main.js',
   component: './resources/js/component.js'
   // etc, etc
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/assets/js'),
    filename: '[name].min.js'
  },

}
```

If your file in entry point need some dependecies for e.g jQuery, you can do it like this.

```
withDeps: ['jquery', './resources/js/withDeps.js']
```